# How to deploy miniProxy?

Tags: proxy

I want to deploy a miniProxy. https://github.com/joshdick/miniProxy
How do I do this? It has a php file but I can't seem to get it to open up in my browser. I have the latest version of chromeOS. Can someone create a file for me or tell me how to convert?

I tried to open it but it doesn't work.
I have attempted to go to a website to convert it but it does not work. I would greatly appreciate if you could help me!